# No data for each on all() function Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

No Data printed or all() function in laravel after foreach and print function
**Product Controller**

```
use App\ProductsCategory;
use App\ProductsSubCategory;
  public function create()
{
    $categories = ProductsCategory::all();
    $subcategories = ProductsSubCategory::all();
    return view('admin.product.create', compact('categories','subcategories'));
}
```

**Create.blade**

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
{{ $category->category_name }} // no data printed
            @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
                @if($subcategory->parent_category_id == $category->id)
                    {{ $subcategory->subcategory_name }}  // no data printed
                @endif
            @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**Product Category Table**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      id             |    category_name |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |    Category 1    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |    Category 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

**Product Sub Category Table**

```
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------|
|      id             | subcategory_name |parent_category_id | 
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------|
|          1          |  Subcategory 1   |     1             |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------|
|          2          |   Subcategory 2  |     1             |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------|
```

Comment: you should add relationship  https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: What do you get if you do `dd($categories->count(), $categories->first());` before the return statement in your controller?

Comment: @Rwd it is show the results of count and first function

Comment: Could you plz add your models ?

Comment: I kind of assumed it would give you that :). What is the count? Is `first()` actually returning a model or is it returning `null` (or, for whatever reason, something else entirely)? Going from the comment in your blade file I'm assuming that you want to find out why `$category->category_name` isn't outputting anything?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already defined models relationships

```
//App\ProductsCategory
public function subCategories() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\ProductsSubCategory', 'parent_category_id', 'id');
}

//App\ProductsSubCategory
public function parentCategory() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductsCategory', 'parent_category_id');
}

//Controller
//...
public function create()
{
    //use [eager loading][1] 
    $categoriesWithSubCategories = ProductsCategory::with('subCategories')->get();
    return view('admin.product.create', compact('categoriesWithSubCategories'));
}

//Create.blade.php
@forelse($categoriesWithSubCategories as $category)
     {{ $category->category_name }}
     @forelse($category->subCategories as $subcategory)    
         {{ $subcategory->subcategory_name }}
     @empty
     <p>No sub categories found</p>      
     @endforelse
@empty
<p>No categories found</p>
@endforelse
```